# How to pass input field name with a post request in swagger-express

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

How to pass input field name with a post request in swagger-express,
I am using below code-

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * path: /get_city_list
 * operations:
 *   -  httpMethod: POST
 *      summary: provide supplierId and accessToken
 *      notes: Returns a list of city corresponding to its supplierId
 *      responseClass: Supplier
 *      nickname: getCityList
 *      consumes: 
 *        - text/html
 *      parameters:
 *        - name: accessToken
 *          description: Your AccessToken
 *          paramType : body
 *          required: true
 *          dataType: string
 *        - name: supplierId
 *          description: Your SupplierID
 *          paramType : body
 *          required: true
 *          dataType: string
 */
```

and if i pass like this i am getting an error
"message": "invalid json",

Comment: It's not clear from the API definition, what does API consumes and also you have multiple parameter definition for body. Does API accept data something like this :
`{"accessToken" : "token", "supplierId" : "id"}`

Comment: @PhagunBaya yes you are right api accept {"accessToken" : "token", "supplierId" : "id"} these field and i have to use swagger-express for documentation with a post request

Comment: OK. Please check the answer. Let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

So, your API def should look like :

```
path: /get_city_list
  operations:
    -  httpMethod: POST
       summary: provide supplierId and accessToken
       notes: Returns a list of city corresponding to its supplierId
       responseClass: Supplier
       nickname: getCityList
       consumes: 
         - application/json
       produces:
         - application/json
       parameters:
         - in: body
           description: data to post
           required: true
           name: body
           type: object
           schema:
             $ref: "#/definitions/PostRequest"
definitions:
  PostRequest:
    properties:
      accessToken:
        type: string
      supplierId:
        type: string
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but it stuck fetching resource get_city_list: localhost:3000/api-docs.json/get_city_list?api_key=special-ke

Comment: swagger.js:478 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: it's work by changing in to paramType and type to dataType..but thing is now i have to pass the response in json object can i direct fill the value here in my case access
Token and supplierId

Comment: OK. It's fine if dataType works for you. I'm on older version of swagger. In my opinion you will need to put the json in hand. Swagger should show you the Model structure on which you can click and get the base structure ready in textarea.

Comment: i didn't get it can you give me the example

Comment: Check this out http://editor.swagger.io and open pet-store example (File > Open Examples > petstore_full.yaml)
Swagger now has a better UI to handle payload.

Comment: Thanks phagun baya